# Validação de um campo em um formulario REGEX

Tags: regex

Bom dia,
Estou com o seguinte problema:
Possuo um regex que valida as seguintes situações:
Não conter ponto, espaço, acentos e/ou letras maiúsculas
"^[a-z0-9]*$"
Queria incluir também para que não permitisse numeros apenas como primeiro caractere, como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode montar a regex em duas parte, a primeira que especifica que o primeiro caracter deve ser uma letra minúscula (`^[a-z]+`) e a segunda que o demais podem ser tanto números quanto letras.

```
^[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*$
```

Comment: Show, era exatamente isso que precisava, muito obrigado!